# Python replace entire column value with last value (from groupby)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
A.       B.         C.
102    01/2020       0
102    02/2020       0
102    03/2020      50
101    01/2020       0
101    02/2020       0
101    03/2020      250
```

In a pandas df, I want to replace all 0's with the last value for each A (by grouping them by column A) as below.

```
A.       B.         C.
102    01/2020      50
102    02/2020      50
102    03/2020      50
101    01/2020      250
101    02/2020      250
101    03/2020      250
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do with `transform`:

```
df['C.'] = df.groupby('A.')['C.'].transform('last')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html#pandas-series-replace)

```py
df['C.'] = df['C.'].replace(to_replace=0, method='bfill')
df
    A.       B.   C.
0  102  01/2020   50
1  102  02/2020   50
2  102  03/2020   50
3  101  01/2020  250
4  101  02/2020  250
5  101  03/2020  250
```

Or
using [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html#pandas-series-where) and [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.bfill.html#pandas-series-bfill)

```py
df['C.'] = df['C.'].where(df['C.'] != 0).bfill()
```